# How to place a Marker on a PNG (or any other image format)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-manipulation

I need a lib recommendation or a solution that allows me to place a marker on a PNG, and save the marker location. The marker has to be a html/css element, allowing the user to click on the marker to open a new window or create a new marker (and save the X-Y loc).

"Why not use leaflet or google maps api?"

I cant use libs like leaflet because I need to use a user's uploaded image (can't be map tiles/layers), and the image can come in different sizes (but not big as a map)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example And also where/how do you intend to store the marker positions?

Comment: Actually, after browsing alot of google, I found a way to use leaflet without preprocessed map tiles. Basically What i've done so far. https://codepen.io/renanreddy/pen/bGYyQyV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lack of knowledge made me think map libs wouldn't work for me, after a little research I found out leaflet do what I needed. I found a way to use leaflet without preprocessed map tiles. Basically What i've done so far. codepen.io/renanreddy/pen/bGYyQyV  I guess thats what I was looking for. Still have the issue of "any image size", but its a start.